# SilverStripe character limit for TextareaField

Tags: php, silverstripe

There seems to be no `maxLength` parameter for `TextareaField` as there are for `TextField`.

What's a good way to limit characters for `TextareaField`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faloude, try doing something like `$yourTextarea = TextareaField::create('yourField')->setAttribute('maxlength', 15);`

You can set attributes on a form field if there isn't a pre-defined method for it in SilverStripe in this way.

Comment: Alright I just found out that it just adds maxlength HTML attribute to the input field, well that works nicely for the moment.